# Java Generics - Get and Put Principle exceptions

Tags: java, list, generics, collections, wildcard

I'm currently studying generics for my programming class, and while reading past examination papers, I came across the question:

`Give an example of a wildcard definition we might use when we want to get items from a
collection object? Give a wildcard definition we might use when we wish to put items into a
collection? What are the exceptions in each case?`

I know that an extends wildcard (? extends T) should be used to 'get' values from a collection object and a super wildcard (? super T) should be used to 'put' values into a collection object, but where are the exceptions?

Comment: This is really too vague.  The definition of `get()` depends on the specific collection interface, so the exceptions that could be thrown also depend on the interface.  This is why `get()` is not defined in `java.util.Collection<E>` but a couple of levels down the inheritance hierarchy, so each collection type (List, Set, Map, etc) can specify its own behavior and method signature.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Check the StackOverflow's help on asking questions first, please. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_(Java) - it's all in there